# Can this kind of "variant fraction notation" be created in latex?

Tags: fractions

I'd like to be able to write math that looks a little like this:

[image: Logical formula]

So it is a bit like a fraction, but there's a also a top line, and there's an arbitrary symbol or formula immediately left of where the top line begins. Can this kind of thing be created in latex? I'd like to have a command `\varfrac{}{}{}` so that the above formula can be written as `\varfrac{\forall}{x:X}{P(x) \& Q(x)}`.

(I couldn't think of any appropriate tags for the question.)

Comment: curiosity kills the duck ... but nevertheless I have to ask: What it is supposed to be? What it is used for?

Comment: @yo', don't worry, goblins don't kill; in fact we are all vegetarians and hippies. Haha. Its meant to be a slight variant on the usual notation of [first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) that improves readability in certain contexts.

Comment: ah ok, FO is cryptic anyways, doesn't hurt making it even more cryptic :p Just one more thing: where is the centerline supposed to be? If it was like `$X=\varfrac{\forall}{x:X}{P(x) \& Q(x)}$`, where would `$X=$` go?

Comment: @yo', good question. It should be aligned with the "usual" fraction line, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very basic one.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx}

\newcommand*\varfrac[3]
  {\frac{\hphantom{#1}\overset{\mathllap{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$#1$}}\hrulefill}{#2}\hphantom{#1}}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \varfrac{\forall}{x : X}{P(x) \mathbin{\&} Q(x)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful with `\varfrac{\forall}{x:X}{P(x)}`, the `\mathllap` makes some troubles there.

Comment: You are right. I think it's solved. I didn't care about fractions in `\textstyle`, I think it's too much to put *inline*.

Answer (score 8):

Use a nested `\dfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\deduction}[4][]{%
  \dfrac{#1\dfrac{#2}{\mathstrut #3}\hphantom{#1}}{\mathstrut #4}%
}

\renewcommand{\land}{\mathbin\&}

\begin{document}
\[
x\quad\deduction[\forall]{}{x:X}{P(x)\land Q(x)}\quad x 
\]
\end{document}
```

Instead of using `\&` in the formula, I'd prefer to redefine `\land` (that usually gives a wedge symbol). Actually I'd avoid the ampersand for denoting the “and” connective, but the document is yours.

For generating the picture, I used `\boxed` in order to show that the bounding box is correct. The two *x*'s on the sides are just to show what's the main fraction line.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply go with multiple `\frac` and a bit of tweaking to get the right font size. Note that this way, the symbol `\forall` will be always properly vertically centered.

As well, you probably want `\mathbin{\&}` since it's a binary operator in your context, and you may want to add some horizontal spacing around `x:X` as I did, to separate it slightly from the `\forall`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
% \samefrac: typeset the inside without style change
\newcommand*\@samefrac[3]{\frac{#2\,#1\,}{#2\,#3\,}}
\newcommand*\samefrac[2]{\mathpalette{\@samefrac{#1}}{#2}}
% \varfrac: the requested command
\newcommand*\varfrac[3]{\frac{#1\samefrac{}{#2}}{#3}}
% \band: binary operator `&`
\newcommand*\band{\mathbin{\&}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\(
    X = \varfrac{\forall}{x : X}{P(x) \mathbin{\&} Q(x)}
\)
\lipsum[4]
\[
    X = \varfrac{\forall}{x : X}{P(x) \mathbin{\&} Q(x)}
\]
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```